# How to scale div content but not div itself and make it work with position: sticky elements?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, sticky

Here's the basic layout I need to scale:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.sticky-row-header {
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sticky-column-header {
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.sticky-column-header-inner {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 300px;
  left: 300px;
  background-color: #6ae;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sticky-column-header">
    <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column1</div>
    <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column2</div>
    <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column3</div>
    <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column4</div>
    <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sticky-row-header">Row1</div>
  <div class="sticky-row-header">Row2</div>
  <div class="sticky-row-header">Row3</div>
  <div class="item">Item</div>
</div>
```

The layout has some sticky columns and rows (the example is primitive, in real case there're nice backgrounds preventing from overflow). Columns are vertically-sticky (they scroll horizontally but not vertically), rows are horisontaly-sticky.

The task is to scale the content. If `transform: scale(0.7)` applied to `.container` itself, it's dimensions change, and the container does not cover the entire window anymore. What I need is the container itself to have the same scrollbars at the edges of the screen, but everything inside to be smaller.

Then I try to put the content inside another `.scale-container`, but this leads to weird behavior for sticky elements:

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scale-container {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: scale(0.7);
}

.sticky-row-header {
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sticky-column-header {
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.sticky-column-header-inner {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 800px;
  left: 2000px;
  background-color: #6ae;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scale-container">
    <div class="sticky-column-header">
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column1</div>
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column2</div>
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column3</div>
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column4</div>
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky-row-header">Row1</div>
    <div class="sticky-row-header">Row2</div>
    <div class="sticky-row-header">Row3</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Namely, sticky containers become *partly* sticky. Is it a chrome bug? How to avoid it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is because you apply a transform to your `.scale-container`

I removed `transform: scale(0.7)` and it works as expected. You should rethink your approach, why do you even need the scaling here? You can just use a smaller font size or something. Or set the overflow on the transformed element, if it's really necessary.

One note: The scroll effect stops after some time, but I guess this also happens because of your setup of absolute positioned elements. Why do you need them here, what is the benefit of your setup. Check if you can refactor it and use less code to achieve the desired result.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  overflow: auto;
}

.scale-container {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  /*transform: scale(0.7);*/
}

.sticky-row-header {
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  position: sticky;
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.sticky-column-header {
  top: 0;
  height: 20px;
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.sticky-column-header-inner {
  flex: 0 0 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  top: 800px;
  left: 2000px;
  background-color: #6ae;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="scale-container">
    <div class="sticky-column-header">
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column1</div>
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column2</div>
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column3</div>
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column4</div>
      <div class="sticky-column-header-inner">Column5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="sticky-row-header">Row1</div>
    <div class="sticky-row-header">Row2</div>
    <div class="sticky-row-header">Row3</div>
    <div class="item">Item</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this is the whole point of the question. I need to scale the content with sticky elements. Yes, it works without scaling, and the first example shows exactly this. `transform: scale(0.7)` seems to be a suitable solution for scaling the content, but for some reason it does not work with sticky. In the real application scaling is dynamic (it's not just 0.7, a user picks the required zoom level).

Comment: To achieve a result that works for you you should try different html structure. You are using header and columns, maybe use a table instead? Does your container need to be positioned absolute?